# Remote Desktop Connection with Selenium WebDriver and VS C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remote-desktop

I'm trying to set up Selenium Remote Web Driver to run tests on computer which i connect through remote desktop connection. Remote computer is on sth like xx.xxxxxxx.com:3389 and i have to type login and password to connect.

I've tried to set up grid, but i dont know how to connect node to hub. On command line i get ip address, but its local (10.xx.xx.xx), so it won't work.

Also i've tried to connect with this code:

```
public void BeforeTests()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities chromeCap = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        String[] switches = { "start-maximized" };
        chromeCap.SetCapability("chrome.switches", switches);
        _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://dekstopconn.com:3322/wd/hub"), chromeCap);
    }
```

but i get this error:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://mydesktop.com:1231/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.

Any advices how can i get it to work? To write test i use VS2013 and C#.
Thanks for help.

EDIT:
I'm not familiar with wireshark, so i get only this, if u need more informations, tell me exactly what u need
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK8nA.jpg)

Comment: Run a wireshark trace and tell us what you seen when this statement executes: _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://dekstopconn.com:3322/wd/hub"), chromeCap);